# Email notification whenever a comment is created via WP REST API

Tags: ajax, wordpress, vue.js, single-page-application, wordpress-rest-api

I'm building a custom comment form for my [Vue.js & WordPress Single Page Application theme](https://wue-theme.app) and was able to post a comment via ajax POST request to the WP REST API. But I don't get any admin notifications on a new comment even the settings in Settings-->Reading are set to notify the admin each time a comment is created/added.

So how can I get email notifications on WP REST API comment creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any reason the WP REST API team didn't use the function `wp_new_comment` whenever a comment is added/created. This function includes the `comment_post` action hook which, in turn, is used by WordPress to send admin notifications in `wp-includes/default-filters.php`.

Instead they've used the `wp_insert_comment()` function which is defined in `wp-includes/comments.php` and which also includes an action hook of the same name `wp_insert_comment` at the very end of the function. This hook we can use to trigger the notification function `wp_new_comment_notify_moderator()`. Just add the following snippet into your theme's / plugin's functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_comment', 'wp_new_comment_notify_moderator' );
```

see also:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/40352

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-api-comments-not-sending-notifications/#post-8987973

Comment: It seems to work, except for replies. Is there any trick so it can work for replies too?

Comment: Hey. Can't confirm. Just tested it on my dummy dev site - I get an email notification when adding a reply to an existing comment. And I have only this one action hook related to comments in the theme.

Comment: this code works great when using rest API. but when I send comments through the website it sends two notification emails. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: @Sadegh
You mean you get the same notification email twice when adding the action hook to the functions.php? 
What do you mean by "when I send comments through the website"? Does your site not use the REST API for sending comments? Then you shouldn't need this hook at all. Not sure what's actual problem is in your case.

Comment: @TechNomad  I have a WordPress website and an android app. website working correctly and the android app works by using REST API.
When someone comments on a post on the WordPress website it sends 1 email to the moderator.
When someone comments on a post on the android app (that works with REST API), it doesn't send an email to the moderator.
When I add this hook to my theme's function.php my android app works correctly. but when someone comments on a post on the website, it sends an email twice to the moderator.

Comment: @Sadegh
ok, I understand now, but obviously when you add the action hook from above, then the `wp_new_comment_notify_moderator` function gets called twice on your website. Just wrap the hook within an if condition which checks for rest api request being processed like this: `if(defined('REST_REQUEST')){add_action( 'wp_insert_comment', 'wp_new_comment_notify_moderator' );}`. Check this link for other options: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221202/does-something-like-is-rest-exist

Comment: @TechNomad Thanks for your help. the code doesn't solve the problem. but the solution in the link that you mentioned works:if (strpos($_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-json/') !== false) {add_action( 'wp_insert_comment', 'wp_new_comment_notify_moderator' );}